# Upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 gives error

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, 15.04

Today I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.04. I did the folowing commands:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo do-release-upgrade`

But during the last command, after lots of get messages I get the following error:

```
Error authenticating some packages. Continue? 

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a 
transient network problem. You may want to try again later. See below 
for a list of unauthenticated packages. 

gettext 
lib32stdc++6 
libatomic1 
libfftw3-single3 
libgfortran3 
libgomp1 
libitm1 
libquadmath0 
libstdc++6 
libtsan0 
onboard 

Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

How can I upgrade without these errors? I have tried similar questions but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to upgrade to 15.04, you will have to download the 15.04 image from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/

Then you will need to create a bootable USB drive with that file, and boot from it. When the installer is loaded, you will be given an option to upgrade the existing Ubuntu installation.

That being said, you should still back up all your files just in case, and it's probably easier if you wait for 16.04, unless you absolutely need 15.04 for something.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04 directly is not supported. You'd have to do 14.04->14.10->15.04, which will not work, as 14.10 has reached End of Life. Last but not least, 15.04 itself will reach EoL is January 2016, which makes upgrading unworthy.

I'd recommend staying on 14.04, and upgrading to 16.04 in due course (in summer 2016).

Comment: if i wanted to though how could i do it?

Comment: @DanielGee You can try the hard way. Charge up the hill, learn what's needed, and solve all the problems on the way. Success is not guaranteed, but it's not impossible.