# update-manager: upgrade to 15.04 rather than 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I want to perform an upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04.
When I run "sudo update-manager -d" I get "... However, Ubunutu 16.04 LTS is now available(you have 14.04)" I think that this nighly build 16.04 is not yet stable.
How to upgrade to 15.04 and not 16.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 gives error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/713371/upgrade-from-14-04-to-15-04-gives-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use update manager without the "-d" option. See man update manager for details.

The -d option means update to development release.

> -d, --devel-release
>                 Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-manager.8.html

or run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

See [How to Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588019/how-to-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04)

Comment: without -d I got "The software on this computer is up to date"

Comment: result of "sudo do-release-upgrade" : "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found"

Comment: OIC, 14.10 is beyond end of life and you can not skip releases, so you can not either upgrade 14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.04 nor can you 14.04 -> 15.04. My advice is for you to do a fresh install of 15.04 , faster and more reliable.